# How to center a Tkinter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have Tkinter window with `canvas` and `label` with 200x200 picture on it.
I want `label` to be in the center of the window, regardless of the window size.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw

imgsize = (200,200)
canvas_bg = "#000000"

root = Tk()
## root.geometry("350x350")

panel = PanedWindow()
panel.pack(expand=0)

canvas = Canvas(panel, bg=canvas_bg)

blank_source = Image.new('RGBA',imgsize, "#ffffff")
blank = ImageTk.PhotoImage(blank_source)

label = Label(canvas, image=blank)
label.configure(image = blank)

canvas.pack( expand=0)
mainloop()
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `place` geometry manager. Here is a simple example :

```
from tkinter import *

wd = Tk()
wd.config(height=500, width=500)
can = Canvas(wd, bg = 'red', height=100, width=100)
can.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
```

Basically the options work as follows:

With `anchor` you specify which point of the widget you are referring to and with the two others you specify the location of that point. Just for example and to get a better understanding of it, let's say you'd be sure that the window is always 500*500 and the widget 100*100, then you could also write (it's stupid to write it that way but just for the sake of explanation) :

```
from tkinter import *

wd = Tk()
wd.config(height=500, width=500)
can = Canvas(wd, bg = 'red', height=100, width=100)
can.place(x=200, y=200, anchor=NW)
```

`relx` and `rely` give a position relative to the window (from 0 to 1) : 0,4*500 = 200
`x` and `y` give absolute positions : 200
`anchor=NW` makes the offset options refer to the upper left corner of the widget

You can find out more over here :

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm

And over here :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm

Comment: Just to be clear: `place` is _a_ way to accomplish the task, not the only way to accomplish the task.

Comment: I would recommend using `pack(anchor='center')` instead, unless you have a specific reason for using `place`.

Comment: @jangler how to anchor using grid?

Comment: For side by side pictures :

`framel = tk.Label(framee, bg='pink', image = None)
 framel.place(relx = 0.1, rely= 0.1, relwidth=0.8,relheight=0.8)

sl = tk.Label(framel, bg='orange', image = self.current_img)
sl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=E)

sr = tk.Label(framel, bg='orange', image = aa)
sr.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=W)
`