# Anchor tag in Tkinter generates a 'bad option' error

Tags: python, tkinter

When I am adding the anchor tag in Tkinter it generates an error that anchor is a bad option.

My code is:

```
textbox=Entry(window,width=50)
textbox.grid(row=1,column=1,anchor=CENTER)
```

Error is:

> +self._options(cnf,kw)
>   _tkinter.TclError: bad option "-anchor ":must be -column,-columnspan,-in,-ipadx,-ipady or -sticky

What else I can use to center the widgets in Tkinter?

Comment: I suggest you to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736465/how-to-center-a-tkinter-widget) explaining about how to center a Tkintor widget

Comment: The error is telling the truth: `anchor` isn't a supported option. What do you expect `anchor=CENTER` to do?

Answer (score 1):

`grid` method does not have  the `anchor` option, you should use `sticky`

example:

```
textbox=Entry(window,width=50)
textbox.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='wnse')
```