# Grouping Tkinter Labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple code,

```
            Monday = Label(master, text="Subject")
            Monday.grid(row=1, column=0)
            Monday = Label(master, text="Monday")
            Monday.grid(row=1, column=2)
            Tuesday = Label(master, text="Tuesday")
            Tuesday.grid(row=1, column=3)
            Wednesday = Label(master, text="Wednesday")
            Wednesday.grid(row=1, column=4)
            Thursday = Label(master, text="Thursday")
            Thursday.grid(row=1, column=5)
            Friday = Label(master, text="Friday")
            Friday.grid(row=1, column=6)
```

[image]

Is there a quick way I can select all of these and move all the days into the middle of the window? I understand I could simply work out the column number for each individual day but surely there is an easier way while also keeping them perfectly spaced out like they are now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Bryan Oakley said, you might do something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(master)

subject = tk.Label(frame, text="Subject")
monday = tk.Label(frame, text="Monday")
tuesday = tk.Label(frame, text="Tuesday")
wednesday = tk.Label(frame, text="Wednesday")
thursday = tk.Label(frame, text="Thursday")
friday = tk.Label(frame, text="Friday")

subject.grid(row=0, column=0)
monday.grid(row=0, column=1)
tuesday.grid(row=0, column=2)
wednesday.grid(row=0, column=3)
thursday.grid(row=0, column=4)
friday.grid(row=0, column=5)

frame.pack(expand=True)

master.mainloop()
```

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738568/13597979) for more info on why the `place` or `pack` method can be used to center things.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do what you want, but the best solution for your specific case depends on what else you're adding to the window.

However, as a general rule, if you want to treat a block of widgets as a group, it's best to create a frame for them, then layout the widgets in that frame however you want. You can the use `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the frame, independent of what you used for the widgets inside the frame.